# Modal for React router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just got that the modals and React Router DOM are not so easly working together.
I tried a lot of different solutions but none worked.

here a piece of code of my Home page:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import AddBtn from "../layout/AddBtn";
import AddTaskModal from "../tasks/AddTaskModal";
import EditTaskModal from "../tasks/EditTaskModal";

<Fragment>
      <SearchBar />
      <div className="container">
        <AddBtn />
        <AddTaskModal />
        <EditTaskModal />
          </Fragment>
```

when the page loads the first time the modals are working.
When I change the page (/about for example) using the Router then I go back to home and the modals are not working anymore.

Does someone know why?
Thanks!

Comment: Working of modals has nothing to do with React Router DOM. Post the problem that you faced.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ReactDOM.createPortal`. Portals are ways to render elements otside of component hierarchy. Below, an example of Portal usage to build a modal:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

const Modal = props => {
    return ReactDom.createPortal(
        <div
            onClick={props.onDismiss}
            className="ui dimmer modals visible active"
        >
            <div onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} className="ui standard modal visible active">
                <div className="header">{props.title}</div>
                <div className="content">
                    {props.content}
                </div>
                <div className="actions">
                    {props.actions}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>,
        document.querySelector('#modal')
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

And, on index.html:

```html
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="modal"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot!
just an explanation, is Modal a module to use combined with the rest of the page ?

Comment: Yes. On your code you have AskModal and EditModal modules, the module Modal is just an example to you change these modules.

Comment: thanks a lot!
I'm not capable to implement it right now but I will!

Comment: You can send me a message, if I can I'll help